# How to Passing Data using Navigator.pop if Navigator.pushReplacement is called Before

Tags: flutter, navigation

as I mentioned in title
Illustrate,
I have 3 screen `Screen A`, `Screen B` and `Screen C`
with flow on below:

`Screen A` - push -> `Screen B`

`Screen B` - pushReplacement -> `Screen C`

`Screen C` - pop(context, value) -> `Screen A`

I want try to get value from Screen C to Screen A but failed, because PushReplacement will pop automatically first. Then how to get value from `Screen C` when navigating back to `Screen A`?

reproduce code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ScreenA(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen A'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            final result = await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenB()),
            );

            print('the result in screenA: $result');
          },
          child: Text('Open Screen B'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen B'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenC()),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Open Screen C'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenC extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen C'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'Print this');
          },
          child: Text('Pop to Screen A'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try using a state management for example provider#

Comment: try it with pushAndRemoveUntil, where your remove the screenB. link to function: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html

Comment: @Halim already use. But Screen A Screen B and Screen C should stand alone

Answer (score 0):

I achive the problem with two option

### A. dont use `pushReplacement`

Then use `push` instead and `pop` manually by `await`

**Screen A**

```
final dynamic result = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenB()),
);

print('the result in screenA: $result');
```

**Screen B**

```
final dynamic result = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenC()),
);

print('the result in screenB: $result');

/// Pop Manually
if(context.mounted) Navigator.pop(context, result);
```

**Screen C**

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'Value');
```

### B. Wrapping `Screen C` with `WillPopScope`

For note you can use `Navigator.maybePop(context);` for triggering all function inside `onWillPop` params

```
class ScreenC extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // pop Screen C to Screen B
        Navigator.pop(context);
        // pop Screen B to Screen A
        Navigator.pop(context, 'Get Value'); 
        
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screen C'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // use maybePop for trigger onWillPop function
              // Navigator.maybePop(context);
              
              // or Navigator.pop manually
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pop(context, 'Get Value');
            },
            child: Text('Pop to Screen A'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Vote Up if this usefull. Thanks